# YouTube API, Can I add a developer tag to an uploaded video?

Tags: youtube

My youtube videos have no developer tag and now I want to add one for them

I can get the videoEntry for those videos
I can add new developer tag as new MediaCategory
I can add MediaCategory as new Category to my video entry (displayed fine)

After I called VideoEntry.update() and use my own function to display the developer tag, it shows me the video has no dev tag. The function is working since I tested with my newly uploaded video(with dev tag during uploaing process)

My question is, Is it possible to add a developer tag after a video had been uploaded.

If possible, What's the essential steps? Do I use VideoEntry.update() ?

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the same problem.  According to [this](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos.html#Assigning_Developer_Tags), you cannot add developer tags after the video has been uploaded.  I do not know why Youtube has this restriction.